# Error using model.fit on MNIST deep neural network training TensorFlow 2.0

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to train a Deep Neural Network using MNIST dataset, here is some of the code of my jupyter notebook:

The first block works fine:

```
# Select the hyperparameter batch size
BATCH_SIZE = 100
# Batch the train, validatiion and test data
train_data = train_data.batch(BATCH_SIZE)
validation_data = validation_data.batch(num_validation_samples)
test_data = test_data.batch(num_test_samples)
# Transform the validation data into tuples for the inputs and targets
validation_inputs, validation_targets = next(iter(validation_data))
# Defining model hyperparameters
input_size = 784
output_size = 10
hidden_layer_size = 50
# Defining the model
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28, 1)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(hidden_layer_size, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(hidden_layer_size, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(output_size, activation='softmax')
])
# Select the optimizer algorithm and the loss function
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

This last block is where I get the error

```
# Defining hyperparameter number of epochs
NUM_EPOCHS = 5
# Training the model
model.fit(train_data, epochs=NUM_EPOCHS, validation_data=(validation_inputs, validation_targets), verbose=2)

Epoch 1/5
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
DataLossError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
      2 NUM_EPOCHS = 5
      3 # Training the model
----> 4 model.fit(train_data, epochs=NUM_EPOCHS, validation_data=(validation_inputs, validation_targets), validation_steps=1, verbose=2)

~\Anaconda3\envs\PY3-TF2.0\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py in _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
     64   def _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
     65     if not self._in_multi_worker_mode():  # pylint: disable=protected-access
---> 66       return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
     67 
     68     # Running inside `run_distribute_coordinator` already.

~\Anaconda3\envs\PY3-TF2.0\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_batch_size, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
    846                 batch_size=batch_size):
    847               callbacks.on_train_batch_begin(step)
--> 848               tmp_logs = train_function(iterator)
    849               # Catch OutOfRangeError for Datasets of unknown size.
    850               # This blocks until the batch has finished executing.

~\Anaconda3\envs\PY3-TF2.0\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwds)
    578         xla_context.Exit()
    579     else:
--> 580       result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
    581 
    582     if tracing_count == self._get_tracing_count():

~\Anaconda3\envs\PY3-TF2.0\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py in _call(self, *args, **kwds)
    609       # In this case we have created variables on the first call, so we run the
    610       # defunned version which is guaranteed to never create variables.
--> 611       return self._stateless_fn(*args, **kwds)  # pylint: disable=not-callable
    612     elif self._stateful_fn is not None:
    613       # Release the lock early so that multiple threads can perform the call

~\Anaconda3\envs\PY3-TF2.0\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
   2418     with self._lock:
   2419       graph_function, args, kwargs = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
-> 2420     return graph_function._filtered_call(args, kwargs)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
   2421 
   2422   @property

~\Anaconda3\envs\PY3-TF2.0\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in _filtered_call(self, args, kwargs)
   1663          if isinstance(t, (ops.Tensor,
   1664                            resource_variable_ops.BaseResourceVariable))),
-> 1665         self.captured_inputs)
   1666 
   1667   def _call_flat(self, args, captured_inputs, cancellation_manager=None):

~\Anaconda3\envs\PY3-TF2.0\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in _call_flat(self, args, captured_inputs, cancellation_manager)
   1744       # No tape is watching; skip to running the function.
   1745       return self._build_call_outputs(self._inference_function.call(
-> 1746           ctx, args, cancellation_manager=cancellation_manager))
   1747     forward_backward = self._select_forward_and_backward_functions(
   1748         args,

~\Anaconda3\envs\PY3-TF2.0\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in call(self, ctx, args, cancellation_manager)
    596               inputs=args,
    597               attrs=attrs,
--> 598               ctx=ctx)
    599         else:
    600           outputs = execute.execute_with_cancellation(

~\Anaconda3\envs\PY3-TF2.0\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     58     ctx.ensure_initialized()
     59     tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
---> 60                                         inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     61   except core._NotOkStatusException as e:
     62     if name is not None:

DataLossError:  truncated record at 15713022
     [[node IteratorGetNext (defined at :4) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_957]

Function call stack:
train_function
```

I have no idea where exactly is the error. I have already tried changing some of the arguments of the model.fit method, like aggregating validation_steps argument, but it didn't work. Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: From [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/errors/DataLossError): `Raised when unrecoverable data loss or corruption is encountered`

Comment: Thanks, but how should I deal with that error? is it the fault of the tensorflow-datasets module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the issue by changing the version of the tensoflow-datasets module, I was using version 3 and by going back to version 2.1 the script worked.